# How to place a figure/image next to TOC element

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents

I am searching to put a figure/image next to a TOC chapter element.

At the moment I only found a way to put it just under it but not either before the number of the chapter or after the page.
`\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\protect\includegraphics[height=1\baselineskip]{Image/en.jpg}\par}`

[image: TOC element]

Comment: Define "next to".  To the left of the "6"? before "Machines"? After "MCS"?

Comment: By next to I mean before the 6 or after the 39 

If I can get only after MCS it's fine too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I use the feature of specifying a separate heading in the toc to add the graphic, via lap, if necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill

\section{Normal section}

\section[{\llap{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image}%
  \kern20pt}Left of section number}]{Left of section number}

\section[{Right of title \includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image}}]%
  {Right of title}

\section[{Right of page  number\hfill\rlap{\kern20pt\includegraphics%
  [height=\baselineskip]{example-image}}}]{Right of page  number}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

In response to comments about the use of `\chapter` in the `book` class, and vertical alignment of the image, I provide an additional MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareRobustCommand\addimg[1]{\llap{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}%
  {\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{#1} \kern20pt}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill

\chapter[\addimg{example-image}Left of section number]{Left of section number}

\chapter[\addimg{example-image}Machines d'audit et processus MCO et MCS]{Machines d'audit et processus MCO et MCS}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alright I didn't know we could do such thing ! 

I'm trying to apply this to my chapter definition but I'm getting an error here : 

```\chapter[{\llap{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{Image/en.jpg} \kern20pt}Machines d'audit et processus MCO et MCS}]{Machines d'audit et processus MCO et MCS}
```

It's saying that \@chapter doens't match its definition, maybe it's not possible using ```chapter``` ?

Comment: What document class are you using @Hekmil?

Comment: ```\documentclass[a4paper,openright]{book} ```

Comment: @Hekmil I can get it to work using `\DeclareRobustCommand\addimg[1]{\llap{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{#1} \kern20pt}}` as a definition and then `\chapter[\addimg{example-image}Machines d'audit et processus MCO et MCS]{Machines d'audit et processus MCO et MCS}`.  Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @Hekmil To accomplish a vertical shift, try this: `\DeclareRobustCommand\addimg[1]{\llap{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{#1} \kern20pt}}}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming back here because I didn't notice that the image is showing up on the header where it's used : [image]

I would like to remove the image or put it on the side, if it's possible.